# Cannot install SDK Tools 28.0.3

Tags: android-studio

I have Android Studio 3.4.1.
When I go to SDK Manager, under SDK Tools, it only shows me 26.1.1.
I cannot see SDK Tools 28.0.3
It does show me Android SDK Platform-Tools 28.0.3

Any idea how do I get SDK Tools 28.0.3?
[image: SDK Tools screen shot]

Here are the platforms I have selected and installed:
[image: SDK Platforms screen shot]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try to download it from the official android developers page: 
https://developer.android.com/sdk/older_releases.html

Comment: 28.0.3 is not an Archived SDK.